# how to loop Posts in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php

I am using one snippet.now i need to loop this snippet with database value.how to achieve this?following is my snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
/* image thumbnail */
.thumb {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Style to article Author */
.by-author {
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.3;
    color: #aab6aa;
}

/* Main Article [Module]
-------------------------------------
* Featured Article Thumbnail
* have a image and a text title.
*/
.featured-article {
    width: 482px;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.featured-article .block-title {
    /* Position & Box Model */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    /* background */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    /* Width/Height */
    padding: .5em;
    width: 100%;
    /* Text color */
    color: #fff;
}

.featured-article .block-title h2 {
    margin: 0;
}

/* Featured Articles List [BS3]
--------------------------------------------
* show the last 3 articles post
*/

.main-list {
    padding-left: .5em;
}

.main-list .media {
    padding-bottom: 1.1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
</style>

<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
Articale post
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
            <!-- artigo em destaque -->
            <div class="featured-article">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/482x350" alt="" class="thumb">
                </a>
                <div class="block-title">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor asit amet</h2>
                    <p class="by-author"><small>By Jhon Doe</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.featured-article -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7">
            <ul class="media-list main-list">
              <li class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                  <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/150x90" alt="...">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h4 class="media-heading">Lorem ipsum dolor asit amet</h4>
                  <p class="by-author">By Jhon Doe</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                  <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/150x90" alt="...">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h4 class="media-heading">Lorem ipsum dolor asit amet</h4>
                  <p class="by-author">By Jhon Doe</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                  <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/150x90" alt="...">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h4 class="media-heading">Lorem ipsum dolor asit amet</h4>
                  <p class="by-author">By Jhon Doe</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i need to loop latest post from database and first post must display big image as 482*350 and next posts must be in the side (150*150).Any help is appreciated.

**Updated::**

Post table

```
id|post_title|post_description|featured_image|author_id|created_at|updated_at
```

Comment: How is your Model "Post" structured?

Comment: @mimo,i have updated my question and every time i click on right side post it should show big images like left side

Comment: I assume you have the controller but you need a trick for your blade to show latest post as bigger then the oldest once? is that correct understand? are they at all 4 posts that is shown? (1 big and 3 small), can you post your controller also?

Comment: You still didnt mentioned your "Post" model.. have you created something like this - [Defining Models](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models) ?

Comment: @maytham. absolutely right.right now after doing all type of correction i have deleted every think

Comment: @mimo.in post model i have nothing just basic code

Comment: @mimo you are talking about model, he think you are asking about module ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller you need to fetch the first article and the 3 other ones:

```
$posts = Posts::orderBy('created_at')->take(4)->get();
$firstPost = $posts->pop();
return view('home', compact('firstPost', 'posts');
```

In your template file you can loop through them:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <!-- artigo em destaque -->
        <div class="featured-article">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="{{ $firstPost->featured_image }}" alt="" class="thumb">
            </a>
            <div class="block-title">
                <h2>{{ $firstPost->post_title }}</h2>
                <p class="by-author"><small>By {{ $firstPost->author->name }}</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.featured-article -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7">
        <ul class="media-list main-list">
          @foreach($posts as $post) {
          <li class="media">
            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
              <img class="media-object" src="{{ $post->featured_image" alt="...">
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $post->post_title }}</h4>
              <p class="by-author">By {{ $post->author->names }}</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          @endforeach             
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your Post Model you need a relationship to the author, e.g.

```
Class Posts extends Model {
  public function author {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Author');
  }

}
```

Comment: @mimo.thank you for the answer .now i getting error in controller saying array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: Beacuse it's a collection and not an array. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @mimo.thanks it works perfectly. is it possible slide that images .i mean if i click right side post it should display bigger images in left side

Comment: This is some javascript stuff. You can get the information (image url, title and author name) of the right clicked element and the left one and swap them.